# Arduino: convert boolean array to decimal

Tags: arduino, binary, decimal, pow

I have an issue with my Arduino. I am trying to convert a boolean array into an int with this piece of code:

```
int boolean_to_decimal(bool bol[]) {
   int somme=0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      somme += bol[i] * pow(2, 5-i);
   }
   return somme;
}
```

Nothing really impressive but here are my results:

010101 == 20 (instead of 21)

100101 == 36 (instead of 37)

101001 == 40 (instead of 41)

011001 == 23 (**instead of 25**)

etc

Thank you for your time, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using floating-point function `pow()` for integers seems bad because it may contain errors. Try using bit-shifting instead.

```
int boolean_to_decimal(bool bol[]){
  int somme=0;
  for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
    somme += bol[i]*(1 << (5-i));
  }
  return somme;
}
```